# Is it possible to override set and get method in MetadataType?

Tags: c#, .net

This is my sample code

```
public class PublicationMetadata
{
    public bool IsOn
    {
        get { return IsOn; }
        set
        {
            if (value && RealLaunchDate == null)
            {
                RealLaunchDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
            }
            else if (!value && RealStopDate == null)
            {
                RealStopDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
            }
            IsOn = value;
        }
    }
}
```

This is my partial class

```
[MetadataType(typeof(PublicationMetadata))]
public partial class Publication
{
}
```

The thing I want to ask is: is it possible to execute set method of `IsOn` property in `PublicationMetadata` when I do something like : `(Publication) pub.IsOn = true`

Comment: The purpose of a metadata type is to provide metadata.  That's all it does.  It can be used to apply attributes to members of a type but it is not part of that type so it cannot change the implementation of that type.

Comment: What is `pub`? A `Publication` or a `PublicationMetaData`? If it is the first, then you cannot do that, because they are two different types and there is no way to retrieve the `PublicationMetaData` instance to alter (`IsOn` is instance property), unless you allocate it and associate to `pub` in some way. If it is the latter, then you don't need the cast.